# What sort of things do demons want when a person makes a pact with them?

Tags: dnd-5e

Part of my quest I am going to involve an NPC summoning a demon and making a pact, the consequences of which the protagonists must uncover and resolve. However I can't think of anything particularly troublesome or destructive that an NPC might offer up in exchange for getting what they want.

Does anyone know the typical top things that demons would want to trade in exchange for help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Television shows like *Supernatural*, *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*, and *Charmed* often feature characters summoning demons and are a good source of inspiration. Demons are also frequently used as the antagonists in high-level published adventures and adventure paths, so those are also good sources for inspiration. Faerie and fey pacts in fiction can often be reskinned as demon pacts - a good example being the pact between the gentleman with thistle-down hair and Mr Norrell found in *Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell*.

Demons are chaotic evil creatures, driven by greed, hatred, and bloodlust. While specific demon types have their own motivations and approaches, I'll approach the question from a generic perspective.

Greed is a simple one - most demons will go for a chance to accrue personal power, freedom, worshipers or wealth. For a pact, that often means enacting some sort of sacrifice or ritual on a regular basis. In fiction, it's quite common for a character to lose their life/soul/power when they fail to abide by the pact. For example, offering "eternal life", but requiring wealth to be sacrificed regularly -- starting at a silver but doubling every year (which after a couple of decades drives the NPC to war or ruthless despotism).

Freedom to wreak havoc on the material plane is another common theme. Often a demon will use some sort of trickery to fool an unwitting NPC to release it (this works with overconfident NPCs as well, who think they've outwitted the demon only to find out too late they haven't). For example, after some bargaining a woman who wants the eternal love of the prince is given a potion that gives her what she wants but results in his possession by the demon every full moon. The wife is brought back to life for the stated cost of her fingerbone, but that gives the demon power over her dreams.

There's also the type of pact that sows chaos. Here the NPC gets what they want seemingly without an obvious catch, but really it's the unintended consequences that delight the demon. You get the white bull, but the original owner goes to war or starts a blood feud. You get success, but live in paranoia (see the aforementioned Mr Norrell). You get the girl, but her presumed-dead spouse shows up and starts killing your relatives since you're protected by the demon.

Comment: On your "greed" point - Honestly, an easy option I've found is to start with the seven deadly sins, assume the demon enjoys all of them, and then rank them in order of preference. Then have the demon ask for something that sounds innocuous, but will somehow allow them to indulge in something from the top of the list.

Comment: I like this answer, but it doesn't back itself up at all. If the question can be answered with anyone's ideas, it's opinion-based and too broad.

Comment: Come to think of it, Miniman's right. You need to back this answer up with a reference that describes demonic motivations. (Relevant personal experience probably won't work, since there's a high chance it'll be personal experience of something made up without much basis.)

Comment: Given the variety in demons, the question may still be too broad even when limited to 5E demons. I"ll happily upvote a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's very helpful. Don't worry everything I've posted on this site has been downvoted or closed despite an abundance of highly upvoted subjective questions that have been useful to me.